# Working with vectors and transformations

Tags: math, graphics

I am going to write an graphical 2D application that allows user to create polygons and transform them through transformation such as rotation an so on. I was hoping someone can give pro and cons arguments for the different choices I got in my mind. (Its all in Java btw!)

a). Represent vectors by filling matrices with 'real' numbers. This means making a matrix datas tructure that supports multiplication, transposing etc

b). Make a own vector class, such that I can make a matrix class that support those vectors.

Comment: I don't see how a) and b) are different. At the end of the day you are still going to manipulate arrays of numbers?

Answer (score 2):

My personal preference (for my own personal project) is to have separate classes for matrices and vectors.  This allows the language to do a bit more typechecking than if everything was a matrix.

Comment: Yes, having the compiler to verify that you multiply a 'horizontal' vector to a square matrix and a square matrix by 'vertical' vector would be very welcome to me.

Answer (score 1):

For 2D transforms you only need 2-tuple vectors and a 2x2 matrix. Both are trivial to implement. Things like matrix to vector multiplication would take a one-line formula rather than a proper loop.

Since matrices are so small I think it would be easier to store 4 numbers in a matrix and not a list of vectors. At least I'd try this approach first. If you need you can directly accept vectors in a constructor or a factory method (e.g. to create an offset matrix).

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you just need

```
struct xy {float x; float y}
```

and

```
class affine_transformation
{
  float m[6];

  xy transform(xy input) {...}
  ...
  methods rotate(), shear(), scale(), translate()
};
```

See
http://www.willamette.edu/~gorr/classes/GeneralGraphics/Transforms/transforms2d.htm